# Who will be more suitable as recommender?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter

I want to apply for Ph.D. positions next year. I have research experience of more than five years, so I am considering applying for research-based universities mostly. Now I am confused about who I should ask for recommendation letters? I already arranged one LOR from my department head,
I am confused about whom should I choose from these four? All of them know me and they all will write good things I believe.

1. There is an **adjunct professor** who taught a course
   during my studies. He is now the head of a reputed university in my
   country.
2. There is an **assistant professor from another university**, under
   whom I did a project. She is affiliated with my current lab, a collaborator mainly. But I had to perform some experimental
   work for her project (published now, I am 2nd author), so I worked in
   her lab for six months, which is out of the city and I worked there
   as a guest researcher.
3. A third is a **postdoc**, mainly my collaborator or co-author and we published four articles, including one in the top journal in our field. He is doing his second postdoc (a research fellow) in a reputed US university.
4. Another one was **my course instructor** during my bachelor's,
   an assistant professor. I learned a few experiments from her (she
   was not my thesis supervisor but she was well versed in some
   experimental tests so she taught me).

Comment: I reformatted your list to make it more readable - please correct if it I made any mistakes (e.g. you mixed A/B/3/4 so I wasn't 100% sure).

Comment: Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3):

Pick the people who know you and your work best and can give the most detailed reports of their observations.  Unless your reference is a famous individual, it's less important who writes your LOR than what they say about why they recommend you.